# AngularJS Directive templateUrl returns 400 though file URL loads

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a basic directive in a MVC 5 Layout Page with a directive for searching. My problem is that the templateUrl cannot be loaded (400 error). If I enter the URL directly into the browser, I can load the html page without difficulty or error. I cannot find out why the AJAX call to load the page is failing.

**Chrome Debugger**
[image: Chrome debugger]

**This is the HTML page loading in Chrome**

[image: Page loads]

**app.js**

```
(function() {
     var app = angular.module("mainApp");

     app.directive("basicSearch", function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'app/directives/basic-search.html',
            controller: function($scope, search) {
                $scope.keyword = '';
                $scope.exact = false;
                $scope.submitSearch = function () {
                    search.searchByKeyword($scope.keyword, 0, $scope.exact);
                }
            }
        }
     });
}());
```

**basic-search.html**

```
<div>
    <input type="search" ng-model="keyword" name="keyword" />
    <button type="submit" ng-click="submitSearch()"></button>
    <input type="checkbox"ng-model="exact" name="exact" />
    <label for="exact">Exact Match?</label>
</div>
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<html>
     <head>
     <base href="@Request.ApplicationPath" />
     <!--- JS & CS References -->
     <title></title>
     </head>
     <body ng-app="mainApp">
     <!-- Other stuff -->
     <basic-search></basic-search>
     <!-- More other stuff -->
     @RenderBody()
     </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
Here is the successful request (via browser):[image: Good Request]

and here is the one that fails (via Angular directive):[image: Bad Request]

Comment: Compare headers in both cases, maybe there is a difference.

Comment: The template is in a static folder to be served? If you can't access the plain template by the url in your browser angular can't too....

Comment: I can access it. See the **Url Loads** section.

Comment: can you please paste the url inside your browser `http://localhost:8059/app/directives/basic-search.html` & see what is result?

Comment: In a lot of cases this error seems to be caused by the browser cache. Are you doing anything with template caching in any other parts of your code? For example using `$templateCache` to pre-load templates can get this result if the template isn't being loaded for any reason.

Comment: @j_buckley, $templateCache is used by the angular boostrap library, so will look into that and feedback.

Comment: There is no template cache used in this specific app and the template is not being loaded into the template cache either.

Comment: it should be a valid URI construct, but can you rename your template and remove the `-` as a test? perhaps it's causing an issue with the template loader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IE bug that Chris is referring to is a caching error that allows old content to be re-served when using angular's $http and IE.

I've written about the subject here: http://benjii.me/2014/07/ie-is-caching-my-angular-requests-to-asp-net-mvc/

A better fix than removing the bug-fix code is to fix it. Use the following instead:

```
//initialize get if not there
if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
}

//disable IE ajax request caching
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get["If-Modified-Since"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT";
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved it. It seems someone added the following to the module config as an attempt to resolve an IE bug (surprise, surprise):

```
//initialize get if not there
if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
}

//disable IE ajax request caching
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get["If-Modified-Since"] = "0";
```

I removed it, cleared out my cache and it's working fine.