# Serve up web files from different directory - Error 400 Bad Request

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app that uses AngularJS.  I am in the process of organizing the folder structure to be feature based rather than type based.

An example folder structure is now

- App (Folder within main project, at same level as Views)

  - Assets

    - CSS
    - JS
  - Pages

    - Home

      - home.js
      - home.tests.js
      - home.html
    - About (etc)

Now the problem is that when `ui-router` tries to load `home.html` the web server throws a 400 error.  If I go to the file manually in the browser it works.  What is the problem here? Why can I not serve files up from this directory.  Note that I actually right click the 400 message in the console and choose open in new tab. So I know the file I am looking at is the URL being requested from AngularJS

Here is my `ui-router` setup

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: '/app/pages/home/home.html',
    controller: 'mainPageController'
})
```

**Note:**
I serve up a .js file from the same directory which seems to work fine!

Comment: If you're using IIS, you should have a more detailed error message in the IIS logs.

Comment: Does the problem exist only in production or in all environments?

Comment: I am only in dev atm, so using IIExpress.. Here is the error message `2015-10-14 15:19:16 ::1 GET /app/pages/home/home.html - 1904 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/45.0.2454.101+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:1904/ 400 0 87 1`

Comment: Try removing the slash in front of /app in your template url.

Comment: I get the exact same error ;/

Comment: Make sure your cache is cleared after you removed the slash. If in chrome open up dev tools (F12), go to the network tab, check disable cache and reload the page with the network tab still open.

Comment: I've tried this again to no avail.  I still get 400 Bad Request when the template engine tries to load the .html file but if I right click the request in Chrome console and open it in a new tab it works!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and it was caused by another developer trying to fix an IE caching bug.

I found the solution here by Ben Cull: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30014936/710268.

```
//initialize get if not there
if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
}

//disable IE ajax request caching
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get["If-Modified-Since"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT";
```

My problem was that the "If-Modified-Since" header was set to '0' and for some reason that was causing html template files to not load.

Comment: Interesting point, thanks, however I dont think it worked in any browser! I've updated my code accordingly though anyway :)

Comment: It wasn't working in any browser for me either. I just mentioned the IE bug because trying to fix that caching bug is what caused this bug, which ended up breaking in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

By default the router is going to start at the top level of your MVC project (i.e. where your Views and App folder sit) and not the folder where your JavaScript is served from.

So in Angular your templateUrl needs to be App/Pages/Home/home.html.

So in your angular router configuration have the property:

```
templateUrl: 'App/Pages/Home/home.html'
```