# Getting 400 bad request error when using templateurl for angular bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to open an angular ui modal using the following syntax

```
$modal.open({
                templateUrl: filepath,
                controller: controllerName,
                scope: $scope
            })
           .result.then(function () {
               alert('closed');
           }, function () {
               alert('canceled');
           });
```

But the modal fails to open in chrome or IE.

On the chrome console I see a 400 error
[image: error message]

This is what i see in the network tab. The last line is the relevant line
[image]

I am currently forced to use older version of libraries. I am using angularjs 1.2.24, ui bootstrap 0.12 and bootstrap css 3.3.6.

I am guessing this is an atypical issue since i couldnt find anything relevant

when i ran fiddler, this is what i see as the raw header

```
GET http://something.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44400
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
RequestVerificationToken: somethingasdlasjdlasjdflajsdf
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
If-Modified-Since: 0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:44400/someting
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: expandedItems=%5Bnull%5D
```

In the javascript used in the application I am working, I see this line

```
   // Enables Request.IsAjaxRequest() in ASP.NET MVC
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Comment: There's not enough information. Does this happens only in Chrome and IE or happens too in Firefox? Have You checked the Network tab in Chrome to see if the paths are right (templateUrl : **filePath**)?

Comment: I havent checked firefox. I copied the same url out from the network tab and put in the location bar in the crome browser and it loaded fine

Comment: In angular, is there anything added to the http header that breaks it? i.e. did you set http header globally? also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28416551/angularjs-directive-templateurl-returns-400-though-file-url-loads

Comment: resolved the issue. It was $httpProvider causing it